# Retrieving Oracle Cursor with JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, ora-06553

I have been experiencing some frustrations trying to make a simple Oracle cursor retrieval procedure work with JDBC.

I keep on getting an error of "[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETNAME'", but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code in Java:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("call getName(?)");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.execute();

stmt.close();
con.close();
```

Here is my procedure in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getName(cur out SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
        SELECT name FROM customer;
END;
```

The error occurs on `stmt.execute()`.

Thanks in advance.

By the way, I am working with Oracle 10.2.0.

Comment: What JDBC jar file are you compiling & executing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried essentially the same thing and it worked for me.  The only difference was that the Oracle JDBC library I am using does not have a method `registerOutputParameter`; I used `registerOutParameter` instead.  Perhaps you are calling a generic JDBC method instead of the Oracle-specific one that support Oracle types.

The only other explanation I can think of is that your Java code is connecting to the wrong schema, and accessing a different `getName` object.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the method name. Is there any Oracle setting or non-code-related problem that may cause this error?

Comment: Turned out that the cursor works fine with JDBC Oracle thin client, but not with ODBC. Not sure about the cause, since I did enable result sets for ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is wrong.  You should not be returning a raw cursor.  You should call the stored proc and iterate through the ResultSet.

Comment: Depends on the database...  SQL Server and Sybase, for example, can return result sets from a stored procedure -- but in Oracle, you need to return a Cursor.

Comment: No, what I was talking about *two years ago* was returning a raw cursor or ResultSet out of your persistence tier.  You should iterate over it, load the contents into data structure, object, or collection of some kind and close the cursor or ResultSet.  You won't have memory leaks or max # of cursors exceeded that way.  I think you misunderstood.  You might want to reconsider your down vote.